# Unomp does not support asic boost

Tags: mining-pools, asicboost

I setup my [unomp](https://blockgen.net/setup-your-own-mining-pool/) server and connect a cpuminer/minerd to it to mine bitcoin. Everything works like a charm. Then I connect my [INNOSILICON T2](http://www.innosilicon.com/html/t2-17.2t-miner/index.html) to it to mine bitcoin, it gives the following error:

`[2018-12-24 20:00:33.857] [DEBUG] [default] - Pool bitcoin Thread 3 Unknown stratum method from (unauthorized) [ip]: mining.configure.`

Does anyone know why? Maybe unomp does not support new "mining.configure" extension introduced in stratum protocol to enable asic boost? If so, what are unomp alternatives that support asic boost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UNOMP is no longer maintained and development of it stopped before the introduction of Asicboost into stratum. Thus it does not support using Asicboost.

[CKPool](https://bitbucket.org/ckolivas/ckpool-splns/overview) is a mining pool software that that does support Asicboost.